# How to determine that a given map from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ preserves area or not?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I wanted to show whether the following map preserves area or not,
$$f(x,y)=(x+y^2,y+x^2).$$

I tried to draw the graph but as function is not linear, my approach could not work.

Can any one suggest me some approach so that I can work this out?

Comment: Do you know the change of variables formula ? Also, are you dealing with Riemann or Lebesgue integration?

Comment: No Sir .I had just done only real analysis in that reimann steljes intergral only

Answer (score 1):

A linear map $A:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2$ multiplies all areas by the factor $\bigl|{\rm det}(A)\bigr|$. It follows that a $C^1$ map
$$f:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad (x,y)\mapsto \bigl(u(x,y),v(x,y)\bigr)$$
possesses a "local area scaling factor" $\bigl|J_f(x,y)\bigr|$ that continuously changes from point to point. The so-called *Jacobian determinant* $J_f(x,y)$  is given by
$$J_f(x,y)={\rm det}\bigl(df(x,y)\bigr)={\rm det}\left[\matrix{u_x&u_y\cr v_x&v_y\cr}\right]\ .$$
In your example we obtain $\bigl|J_f(x,y)\bigr|=|1-4xy|$, which  is not constant. For an area preserving map we would need $\bigl|J_f(x,y)\bigr|\equiv1$.

Comment: Nice explanation (+1).

Answer (score 0):

If it preserved areas, then $f'(a,b)$ would also preserve areas for each $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. But $\det f'\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)=0$.

Comment: Why Sir? if some function preserve area then that means its derivative also preserve same?

Comment: Indeed. Besides, since $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and since $f(x,y)$ behaves as $f\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)+f'\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)\left(x-\frac12,y-\frac12\right)$ near $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$ and $\det f'\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)=0$, it is clear that $f$ cannot be area-preserving, at least near $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the image under $f$ of the unit square $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$.